# Optimization of a simple Python script to calculate the first sophomore's dream number

Tags: python, math, optimization

I am currently working on a program to calculate 100,000 digits of the first sophomore's dream constant, I1. It's given by the sum below.

[image]

After about 10,000 terms in this series it gets quite slow. I opted to write the program so small because I wanted to see how small I could make it

```
from decimal import *

def sophodream(a):
    s,i,t=0,1,int(a*1.5)
    while i<t:
         print(i)
         n,d=Decimal(pow(-1,i+1)),Decimal(i**i)
         f=n/d
         s+=f
         i+=1
    return s
```

I would like to know if there are any ways to speed this up aside from multithreading/multiprocessing. I find that when I do series like these in threaded pieces the accuracy of them gets lower.

Comment: `pow(-1,i+1)` is just `-1 if i%2 else 1`, saves a few percents. Not sure if you can do anything about `i**i`. Doesn't seem to be faster even with exponentiation by squaring

Comment: Making the program "small" is fine as an exercise for yourself but it makes the code incredibly hard to read and has nothing to do with the problem in question.

Comment: When you have infinite-precision numbers, multiplication and division are O(n^2) and addition is O(n). That makes the overall algorithm O(n^3). So it's going to be slow.

Comment: Ahh, I figured as much. @Jean-FrançoisFabre's idea seems good.

Comment: thanks but this isn't going to speed it up a lot. The problem is `i**i`

Comment: Makes sense, 10000^10000 is a very big number.

Comment: @Woodford I do not normally program like this. I just programmed it in a minified format here for fun. I should have posted it un-minified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some minor changes / simplifications that can be made to your code but as has already been noted, you're working (at times) with some **very** big numbers.

```
from decimal import getcontext, Decimal

def sophodream(a):
    s, p = 0, 1
    getcontext().prec = a
    for i in range(1, int(a * 1.5)):
        s += p / Decimal(i**i)
        p = -p
    return s

print(sophodream(100))
```

**Output:**

```
0.7834305107121344070592643865269754694076819901469309582554178227016001845891404456248642049722689389
```

Obviously just a very short version to prove functionality